# jQuery/AJAX functions executing only once

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery and AJAX to submit and process a form. The form is for a like/unlike button. When the user clicks the like/unlike button, the form gets submitted (I commented out my AJAX in my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TPJUj/2/)) and the form is then changed to the opposite and the button text is changed. But, for some reason, The form and button will only change once. What am I doing wrong? I want a user to be able to hit like, then unlike, and like again if they so wish.

My Code:

```
$(".like-form").submit(function () {

    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    var $this = $(this);

    //Ajax that submits the form to like.php

    $this.attr('class', 'unlike-form');
    $this.find('.like-button').html('Unlike');

    return false;

});

$(".unlike-form").submit(function () {

    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    var $this = $(this);

    //Ajax that submits the form to unlike.php

    $this.attr('class', 'like-form');
    $this.find('.like-button').html('Like');

    return false;

});
```

Comment: Any reason you're using a form for this?

Comment: how else could i do this?

Comment: Added some more notes to my answer and improved the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding the submit event to a form that doesn't exist since you are changing the class of the existing form. The correct way to do this would be:

```
$("form").submit(function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    var isLiked = $this.hasClass('unlike-form');
    var dataString = $this.serialize();

    if ( isLiked ) {
        //Ajax that submits the form to unlike.php
    } else {
        //Ajax that submits the form to like.php
    }

    $this.toggleClass('like-form unlike-form');
    $this.find('.like-button').html(isLiked ? 'Like' : 'Unlike');

    return false;

});
```

I would suggest giving the form a specific attribute so you can select it more directly.

Comment: Exactly what I was writing:) You was faster than me.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is no `'.unlike-form'` when your code is run.

jQuery isn't actively checking your DOM for changes and re-running code in a lopp or anything. *Your* code is static, so when it's executed and tries to bind events it's finding a `.like-form` and binding a click event on that. There is no '.unlike-form'.

Furthermore, you're code is changing the class fo the element, so even if you got the binding code to work, because it's still the same form element, it *still* has the original `.like-form` event code attached to it.

IMO, your whole approach is a bit off. I'd recommend something more like this (not tested):

```
<button class="like-button is-unlike" data-like-button data-user-id="1" data-post-id="2">Like</button>

<script>
  var $likeButtons = $('[data-like-button]');

  $likeButtons.on('click', function() {
    var $likeButton = $(this);
    var isLiked = $likeButton.hasClass('is-liked');

    var data = {
      mode: isLike ? 'like' : 'unlike'
      userId: $likeButton.data('user-id'),
      postId: $likeButton.data('post-id') 
    }

    // do async request here

    if (isLiked) {
      $likeButton
        .removeClass('is-liked')
        .addClass('is-unliked')
        .text('Unlike');
    } else {
      $likeButton
        .removeClass('is-unliked')
        .addClass('is-liked')
        .text('Like');
    }

    return false;
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Made my recommendation code reusable. Just add a `data-like-button` attribute on any element and then run the script **once** at the end of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using switchClass().

```
switchClass(removeClassName, addClassName).
```

Ref : http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/

And change the submit to click function and everything will work fine..